# Действительно ли не нужна запятая после "до самого горизонта"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Пока она спала, тяжелые дождевые тучи заволокли небо Солитьюда до самого горизонта и на улицы легла тень.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Пока она спала, тяжелые дождевые тучи **заволокли** небо Солитьюда до самого горизонта и на улицы **легла** тень.*

Запятая не ставится в ССП с общим придаточным предложением, которое **относится к обоим предложениям.** Это подтверждает **одинаковый** (совершенный) вид глаголов.

Пояснение у Розенталя (когда нужно ставить запятую):

Но: Когда Каштанка проснулась, было уже светло, и с улицы доносился шум, какой бывает только днём (Ч.) — придаточная часть относится только к первому простому предложению, а связь его со вторым слабее, на что указывает различный вид глаголов-сказуемых этих предложений. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133